# Project Makefile and conditional NPM linking

Tags: node.js, makefile, npm

We're a small team and writing a webapp in node.js,express.js and it is bundled with a parser that is implemented in python.

**I would like to use my npm link'd fork of some libraries but not interrupt my team's workflow. So if my forks exist, otherwise install local node packages.**

I would like to play around with deployment scripts so I was writing a Makefile for the project. Part of the makefile's job is to use npm to get the node dependencies, so I have a target

```
node_modules:
  @@(cd $dir && npm install)
```

Which is all fine until I started hacking on some node libraries. Now, I have a few forks of some dependent libraries that I would like to use but don't want to interfere with the rest of my team's build.

The solutions I've seen are *almost* there but not quite. The --link related flags and options will install globally if the global package is not there, which is not what I want. I would like it to install locally.

- **npm link foo** then **npm install** - sort of works, but npm will install *foo* globally if the link does not exist
- **devDependencies** - would be good except we will all be building npm
- Some sort of **per user Makefile** that I just keep locally that runs - this seems like an option that works, but will require some extra cruft that I'd rather not have to take care of.

I only have a bit of experience with Makefiles, so maybe there is a pattern for this already. Any ideas?